# What is a base template in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Started learning Rails, so may this question is obsolete but yet I want to know what exactly it is in rails.

I am trying to create a login form for users, so after googling i came across `devise`(yet not sure what exactly it do, but i gave a try yet).

Link for the tutorial- http://www.slideshare.net/wleeper/devise-and-rails

I am stuck with page 4 of 22 at -

**Add some flash notices into the base template**

[image]

I dont know where i do need to add these line.(things are on localhost) and I would like to know that I really i am following the correct tutorial to create a login form in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base template is `application.html.erb` by default.

Comment: @apneadiving.. can u please comment that I am following the correct tutorial for login page in ROR as I am new to RoR..but able to understand the concepts from my main skill set in PHP..or any other suggestion you would like me to provide

Comment: did you check the railscasts? http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

Comment: thanks for the link and your support, rails sounds interesting to me..rally love to explore more in this :)